# Git merge GitHub pull request commits to branch

Tags: git, github

I have a strange git problem. I'm developing Bitflate, a crypto fork of Bitcoin Core. I have a set of changes for my project. I keep these changes in the master branch. I regularly sync my master branch with the Bitcoin Core codebase. I also keep a pristine bitcoin-master branch to compare the difference between my master branch and bitcoin-master.

I keep the log of commits in a Pull Request on GitHub. It currently has 54 commits.

(master branch to bitcoin-master)

https://github.com/bitflate/bitflate/pull/15

This pull request shows me the specific changes in my project. For release, Bitcoin Core creates a release branch. Currently, it's 0.19 version. I follow the same release approach and versioning. I want to apply the 54 commits of my project in pull request #15 to branch 0.19. I don't want to merge master into 0.19 because the master branch has unnecessary changes.

I tried a diff, patch approach but git can't apply the patch. It's too complicated for git to parse. My current approach is to manually cherry-pick these 54 commits to branch 0.19. Maybe, I can write a script to apply the commits. I wonder if there are other approaches.

Update: I find a way to do this. Not sure if it should be an answer to this question.

- Download the patch file from Github: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/bitflate/bitflate/pull/15.patch
- Copy patch file to the codebase directory
- Run: git am --3way 15.patch.

This command will apply each commit into the current branch. It will stop when there's a conflict. In my case, I always want the patch changes.

So, I repeat these steps until no more commit to apply:

- git checkout --theirs . # accept incoming change
- git add . # add all the changes
- git am --continue # continue git patch apply

I checked the end result. Merge commits don't show up. But all the other commits are in.

**Update**: The above method does not work well. This is because the new changes are applied from master branch HEAD. Older changes may not get applied correctly.

My latest attempt is to generate a diff and apply with this command:

- Download diff: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/bitflate/bitflate/pull/15.diff
- Apply: git apply --reject --whitespace=fix 15.diff